# In Symfony kernel.controller event, what is the return type of ControllerEvent::getController()?

Tags: php, symfony

In Symfony 5.3, I have an `EventSubscriber` to the `KernelEvents::CONTROLLER` event.

```php
class PrivateAPIEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    
    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => ['onKernelController', 2],
        ];
    }
    
    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $event): void
    {

        $controller = $event->getController();

        dd($controller);
```

The issue I have is that for most of my requests, the `getController()` method returns array like this:

```
PrivateAPIEventSubscriber.php on line 42:
array:2 [▼
  0 => App\Controller\CP\SecurityController {#241 ▶}
  1 => "login"
]
```

the 0th element is the `$controller` object and the 1st element is the function.

But for an error page (e.g. no route)

```
PrivateAPIEventSubscriber.php on line 42:
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ErrorController {#468 ▼
  -kernel: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel {#141 ▶}
  -controller: "error_controller"
  -errorRenderer: Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\ErrorRenderer\SerializerErrorRenderer {#469 ▶}
}
```

I cannot find documentation for this method, the source code is not helpful (the `$controller` variable inside `ConrtrollerEvent` is not typed) and I am worried that there might be some more cases which I am not handling (like return of larger arrays or multi-dimensional arrays)

So what are all the expected return types?

Comment: It returns a `callable`, so it could be a callable, a closure, an invokable class or even a string.

Comment: In case you are still wondering about the difference, in the first case you have a controller instance along with the name of the method to call.  In the second case you have just the instance since the ErrorController has an _invoke method which is automatically called if no method is specified.  As already noted, both are examples of callables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [source](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/f7a40b1fa20f356cd82920f5810765903075ade8/Event/ControllerEvent.php#L39) is your friend:

```
public function getController(): callable
{
        return $this->controller;
}
```

It's type-hinted, so it's clear that it returns a `callable`. Something you can call. It does not return "different return types", but a single return type that can have multiple shapes, as long as it's a valid `callable`.

To see what the data type details, you can always check the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).